# Labels Flickering On UserFor When I DO A MouseOver

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with flickering labels on my userform, when I do a mouse over. Some labels are grouped. I have ungrouped them but I am still having the flickering issue. For each button I have used 3 labels, 1 for background, 1 for Icon and 1 for text as nothing would position the icon and text as I wanted. **See image**

[image]

**Apart from the flicker they work fine.** I am using labels as buttons as the look better than the vba userform buttons and because, when I tried to you an image as a button, the picture would not display correct, the quality would reduce, but it is fine in a label.

The labels start to flicker when I move the mouse over them, I was looking at these as some possible solution on,[Mr Excel Forum](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-label-update-flicker.866908/) & [My Original Thread on Mr Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/flickering-labels-on-mouse-over.1130654/) (there is a code at the botom of this thread), but I am not 100% sure how to change it for my labels. In the second thread that I posted there is a link to the original question which was raised by another member, within this thread they talk of label groups  "LabelGroup.Parent.Parent.Controls". I have NO idea what this is and how to do it. Please could someone advise of how I can implement one of these codes with my code, useform or guide me to another solution.

**My code is a simple IF statement, that works on a mouse over event**

```
Private Sub MainMenuPageButton_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
'MainMenuPageButton border change green on mouse over
     MainMenuPageButton.BorderColor = 8435998 'change boarder to green
           'Grey Borders for all other labels
            SearchButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
            WebBrowserButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
            SaveFileButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
            EmailButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
            LoadFileButton.BorderColor = -2147483627
            Sheet2Button.BorderColor = -2147483627
            Sheet3Button.BorderColor = -2147483627
            Sheet12Button.BorderColor = -2147483627
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have have since reverted back to using images with a better quality picture. I am still having the same flickering problem. However I have noticed that if an image is selected, the flickering is gone. As a work around I could have it set that on for Initialize an image can be selected, this should then get rid of the flicking issue I am having. I have tried something like `Image1.SetFocus` but that did not work. Please could some one advise of what to do as there was not click option to select from the library for the image.

Comment: I ok I have fixed this, well more of a work around. That is why I have not listed this as an answer. I have placed all the buttons into an Active Control X frame and set the layout to Flat which changes the Borders to NONE. I also used the UserForm1.Repaint as a refresh. The frame has stoppend the flicker and the mouseover works. I will need to place other items into frames that are still flickering as the frame resolves the mouseover flickering.